# react-native-svg ForeignObject element not found (React-Native + Expo + TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-svg

I have a React Native project created with Expo. I also used the expo TypeScript configuration.

I installed **react-native-svg** using "expo install." I currently have version 9.13.3 installed.

Whenever I try to render the SVG using react-native-svg I get this error.

I've looked through the src files of the node module and can't find any files for the ForeignObject element.

---

**Error:**

```
Unable to resolve module `./elements/ForeignObject` from `node_modules/react-native-svg/src/ReactNativeSVG.ts`: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/ForeignObject(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/ForeignObject/index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)

ABI36_0_0facebook::ABI36_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
ABI36_0_0facebook::ABI36_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
B9D95EAB-9269-367D-B2F4-C2B45821A32D
B9D95EAB-9269-367D-B2F4-C2B45821A32D
B9D95EAB-9269-367D-B2F4-C2B45821A32D
7519E999-1053-3367-B9D5-8844F6D3BDC6
7519E999-1053-3367-B9D5-8844F6D3BDC6
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
7B531A15-3E73-3185-90E2-B88D9476DA5E
```

---

Here is my component declaration - **Star.tsx:**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Svg, Defs, Path } from "react-native-svg";

class StarIcon extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

  render() {
    return (
      <Svg width={31.709} height={31.814} viewBox="0 0 31.709 31.814" fill="black">
        <Defs />
        <Path
          d="M15.5,23.7,23.843,29l-2.214-9.99L29,12.288l-9.707-.867L15.5,2l-3.793,9.422L2,12.288,9.371,19.01,7.157,29Z"
          transform="translate(0.355 0.677)"
        />
      </Svg>
    )
  }
};

export default StarIcon;
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, other than it might have something to do with the TypeScript config. I created the same icon in a JavaScript react-native project and it worked fine.

If anyone knows why I'm getting this error or could provide any help I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welp...Turns out I just needed to clean my npm cache...

`expo r -c`

[oof](https://media.giphy.com/media/S3Qafn57JDnsfRfbFc/giphy.gif)